# I use threejs GLTFLoader load a GLTF 3d model,but why it so ugly

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am a frontend rookie & don't know things about OpenGL. I use three.js GLTFLoader to load a 3D model, but it is so ugly, I don't like the preview on the model website at all. How can I update my code to make it look more like the sample output as shown in the image below?

```
  <script>
    const vm = new Vue({
      el: '#root',
      data(){
        return {
          x: 100,
          y: 100,
          z: 100
        }
      },
      mounted(){
        this.initWorld();
        let material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({ color: 0x0000ff });
        Vue.prototype.loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
        this.loader.load(
          './scene.gltf',
          this.onLoadend,
          this.onLoading,
          this.onError
        )
      },
      methods: {
        initWorld(){
          const { innerWidth: w, innerHeight: h } = window;
          const render = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
            alpha: false,
            antialias: true,
          });
          render.setSize(w, h);
          document.querySelector('#root').appendChild(render.domElement);
          const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, w/h, 1, 500);
          camera.position.set(this.x, this.y, this.z);
          camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);
          const scene = new THREE.Scene();
          Vue.prototype.camera = camera;
          Vue.prototype.scene = scene;
          Vue.prototype.render = render;
        },
        refreshRender(){
          this.render.render(this.scene, this.camera);
        },
        changeCameraPosition(x, y, z){
          this.camera.position.set(x, y, z);
          this.refreshRender();
        },
        onLoadend(gltf){
          this.scene.add(gltf.scene);
          console.log(gltf);
          this.scene = gltf.scene;
          this.refreshRender();
        },
        onLoading(xhr){
          console.log((xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100) + '% loaded');
        },
        onError(err){
          console.log(`An error happened: ${err}`);
          throw err;
        }
      }
    })
  </script>
```

I want it to look like
[image: this]
but I'm currently getting this
[image: this]

Comment: You need to add a Bloom post processing pass to get the glow effect. Look in the examples, [this one](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_points_dynamic) has a bloom post processing pass and [this one](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_postprocessing_unreal_bloom) has a more complex bloom post processing pass. To make the points look round you'll need to add a texture to their material like [this example](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_points_billboards.html)

Comment: thanks a lot!! now i get it.haha

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in Three.js either but this worked for me
1) checked your whether your exported glTF file loads correctly with the following viewer?
https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/  if yes and still showing like this

[image]

I recommend you to use glTF Metallic Roughness and glTF specular Glossiness in the scene in order to get the desired output.